# how to manage state with Riverpod on background service in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I'd like to keep showing my step count on notification even on background.

For this, I use package `flutter_background_service`.

```
class StepBackgroundService {
  static const notificationChannelId = "step_foreground";
  static const notificationChannelName = "STEP_FOREGROUND";
  static const notificationId = 1;

  Future<void> initializeService() async {
    final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
    const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      notificationChannelId,
      notificationChannelName,
      description: "This channel is used for step notification.",
      importance: Importance.low,
    );

    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotifiationPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    if (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isAndroid) {
      await flutterLocalNotifiationPlugin.initialize(
        const InitializationSettings(
          iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
          android: AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_bg_service_small'),
        ),
      );
    }

    await flutterLocalNotifiationPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    await service.configure(
      androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
        onStart: onStart,
        autoStart: true,
        notificationChannelId: notificationChannelId,
        initialNotificationTitle: "오늘도청춘",
        initialNotificationContent: "",
        isForegroundMode: true,
      ),
      iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
        autoStart: true,
        onForeground: onStart,
        onBackground: onIosBackground,
      ),
    );
    service.startService();
  }
}

// background
Future<void> onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  const stepCount = 0;
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });
    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });

    service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
      service.stopSelf();
    });
  }

  // background task
  Timer.periodic(
    const Duration(
      seconds: 1,
    ),
    (timer) async {
      if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
        service.setForegroundNotificationInfo(
          title: "$stepCount 걸음",
          content: "",
        );
      }
      service.invoke(
        'update',
        {
          "current_date": DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
        },
      );
    },
  );
}

Future<bool> onIosBackground(ServiceInstance service) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

  return true;
}
```

This is my full background service code.

And in `onStart`, I show my stepCount as my title.

But the problem is my stepCount is coming from fireStore.

And also sometimes it needs to be added like ++.

So I think I need to manage this state and use `riverpod`.

Mostly when I working with riverpod and firestore together, I use `AsnycNotifier`.

```
class StepViewModel extends AsyncNotifier<int> {
  late final StepRepository _stepRepo;

  @override
  FutureOr<int> build() {
    _stepRepo = ref.read(stepRepo);
    return fetchUserTodayStepcountVM();
  }

  // void incrementStep() => ;

  Future<int> fetchUserTodayStepcountVM() async {
    int todayStepCount = await _stepRepo.fetchUserTodayStepCount();
    return todayStepCount;
  }
}

final stepProvider = AsyncNotifierProvider<StepViewModel, int>(
  () => StepViewModel(),
);
```

I have two questions.

**1.** when I get value from AsyncNotifier, I need `WidgetRef` as changing statelessWidget to ConsumerWidget.

But here, I used it on background service, there's no WidgetRef.

So I can't access this value with `ref`.

Is that possible to use riverpod with this case?

---

**2)** I need to increment of stepCount on AsnycNotifier.

However increment method is just ++.

But as you can see below, it says ++ isn't defined for the type AsyncValue and even this method is not related to fireStore.

I just need to get data from fireStore only at first.

In this scenario, AsyncNotifier is fit for my purpose?

Should I use `ChangeNotifier`?

Riverpod and even provider has so many notifiers.. I can't distinguish them.

Please help me.

[image]